# Divide if different than 0

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, division

I often have this kind of statement in my code :

```
(b != 0) ? a / b : a
```

In terms of speed and best C++ pratice, is it better to do a function

```
float divifnotzero(a,b) { ... return ... }
```

or a preprocessor macro like this ?

```
#define divifnotzero(a,b) ((b!=0)?a/b:a)
```

Comment: With this being defined as an inline function, this should not matter with modern, highly optimizing, compilers.

Comment: Profile - it's really the best way.  Really, for a divide, unless you're taking the zero branch a lot, the division is going to dominate any other overhead - that or other things that have nothing to do with macro vs. function (cache stalls, branch misprediction, etc).

Comment: The optimizer will most likely make both solutions result in very similar binaries -- if not exact the same. A lot of functions are inlined by the optimizer as it sees fit, you don't have to worry about this kind of micro optimization.

Comment: One reason to use a function is that your macro is wrong.

Comment: and it's wrong in at least two ways.

Comment: `divifnotzero(a++,b++)` works as function. Macro, not so  much.

Comment: @chris what's wrong? It works here: http://cpp.sh/9oaad

Comment: @Basj What if `divifnotzero(w + x, y / z)`?

Comment: @Basj see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros

Answer (score 9):

The pre-processor is just going to replace the code wherever you use the macro, so there is no difference there. As for a function, your compiler will almost certainly inline it, so again there should be no difference in speed. So, given that I would go with a function for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor macros inline any code you put in them. A function call allows you to reduce the size of the executable at the expense of some slight overhead. Based solely on that, in this instance you would want to use a preprocessor macro.

In practice, functions can be inlined just like preprocessor macros with the `inline` keyword, which gets rid of the overhead. The compiler can generally decide on whether or not to inline a function itself; one like this would almost certainly have that happen. Go for the function call, unless you're specifically compiling the program without optimizations while still valuing speed.

Comment: The `inline` keyword effectively has nothing to do with whether the function will be inlined. Same for whether optimisations are enabled.